how can i download the result of an newman test like in postman
I need to download the result of my Newman test like i would do it in postman.
but i can't seem to figure out how to do that. If i remember correct that is where it would be downloaded in postman []
if anybody knows how to achieve it please let me know.
I tried the reporter JSON and CLI but it wont generate a file for me.
I looked it up in multiple forums but haven't found anything helpful yet.

You need to run 'newman' library in node.js program. For saving each request into json in here or single json file in here.

thx i try it out after converting it into c#

it seems like there is no libary at least i cant find it. im using the command line tool if thats any help

No command line support, you have to use newman library by node.js program.

ehhm there is command line example:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/postman-newman-cli-tool/ and im using it succesful for weeks now just the download button i  cant seem to figure out

In the Postman, "save response to file" can't do by newman CLI. It can do by newman library by node.js program.

oh thats what u meant sorry damn that might be an issue cuz i cant seem to find a c# libary for it thx for the answer

If you still want to how to save response of request by node.js, I can answer in your question. Let me know.

sorry for the late response i found a way to achieve what i need to:

sry pressed enter
sorry for the late response i found a way to achieve what i need to:

i had to install a specific csv reporter for newman 90% of the ones i tried didn't work for me
run " ur path to postman collection " --insecure --folder "requestName" -r csv --reporter-csv-includeBody
then u can read out the csv file in which u have ur body like in postman and ur error code


this reporter is the one that worked for me u can tell it to include the postman body https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-csv
